# Picture overflows div with border

Tags: html, css

How do I ensure that my photo doesn't overflow my border like so:

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
<div className="link__wrapperMain" {...longPressEvent}>
          <div className="link__mediaWrapper">
            <img
              alt=""
              src={imageUrl}
              // style={{ borderRadius: `${imageBorderRadius}` }}
            />
            <img
              alt=""
              src={faviconImage}
              style={{ borderRadius: `${imageBorderRadius}` }}
            />
          </div>
```

```css
.link__mediaWrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: none;
}
```

I thought that my `overflow: none` would work but it doesn't!

Comment: it is `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: @gugateider Doesn't work

Comment: You need to set overflow: hidden; on the white area surrounding the image.

Comment: Please add a working code snippet to demonstrate your problem for future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Then try to change the border radius of image also...
So then it will be done perfectly...

```
.link__mediaWrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: none;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```